# Laravel 5.8 - How to handle API route with optional auth?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-middleware

Can anyone help me to handle API route with optional **Auth** check? I have an **API ROUTE** 'apply-coupon' which can be used by both 'Guest' and 'Logged In' user. I need to get User ID in controller if the user is logged in.

**Front end** - Is developed with React JS, on 'Apply Coupon' button click, an API is calling as -

```
API end point - https://example.com/api/apply-coupon
Request payload - {coupon : 'my-coupon-code', shop_id : '1', subtotal : '150'}
```

**Note :** No token is passed in the header, since 'apply coupon' feature is available for guest user as well.

**Expected output :-** When user clicks on 'Apply Coupon' it should return User ID, if user id logged in.

Following is my route in **api.php** file -

```
Route::post('/apply-coupon', [
    'uses' => 'CouponController@applyCoupon',
]);
```

**Update :-** And the default guard is -

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

I have tried

```
if(Auth::user()) {
     dd(Auth::user());
}
```

and

```
auth()->guard('api')->user()
```

But nothing worked. Thanks!!

Comment: did you try to call middleware on your route? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: I need to protect the route optionally for both guest and logged in user.

Comment: you could try creating your middleware that you could call on your route.

Comment: "when user clicks", doesn't sound like an API

Comment: It's not possible without any kind of token to check current user's identity. you will have to pass token optionally in header. In controller auth()->guard('api')->check() ? auth()->guard('api')->user()->id : NULL

Answer (score 0):

Add one middleware ValidateUser.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;


class ValidateUser
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->bearerToken()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return $this->validateToken($request, $next);
    }

    private function validateToken($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            if (! JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                throw new \Exception('Unable to find the account');
            }
        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Token has been expired');
        } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Token is not valid');
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Unable to parse the token');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your http/kernel.php in

> $routeMiddleware

add

```
'api.auth.validate' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateUser::class
```

Now in your api.php you can use middleware to check it something like:

```
middleware(['api.auth.validate'])
```

Comment: you can try assigning multiple middleware :  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "optionaly" protect routes. What I think you could do is check in your controller if the user is authenticated and if it is, then get its ID. Of course the route should be unprotected

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
...
function applyCoupon() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        // The user is logged in...
        // return Cupon + Auth::id()
    } else {
        // Not logged in code
        // return Cupon
    }
}
```

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)